# Sub domain or Sub directory need to redirect another sub domain or Sub domain

Tags: php, subdomain, redirect

I have a sub domain like **abc.xyz.com**

This sub domain opens with following urls like **abc.xyz.com** or **www.xyz.com/abc**

I need to redirect all this to new sub domain or sub directory of new domain
How can I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Use header redirect

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```